Jolt transform JSON to different JSON structure
Having this structure as response from webservice
{
  "software": [
    {
      "service": "someService",
      "versions": [
        "24.32.1.57-docker",
        "24.32.1.56-docker"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

how to transform it using Jolt spec to following structure required by teamcity webparameters plugin
{
  "options": [
    {
      "key": "24.32.1.57-docker",
      "value": "24.32.1.57-docker",
      "enabled": true,
      "default": "as default first entry in list"
    },
    {
      "key": "24.32.1.56-docker",
      "value": "24.32.1.56-docker",
      "enabled": true
    }
  ]
}


You can use the following transformation :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "versions": {
            "0": { //filter only for the first object as component of the options array 
              "*": {
                "$": ["options[&2].key", "options[&2].value"],//$ replicates the keys from one uper level 
                "#true": "options[&2].enabled",//hardcode by using # sign
                "#as default first entry in list": "options[&2].default"
              }
            },
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "$": ["options[&2].key", "options[&2].value"],
                "#true": "options[&2].enabled"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {//boolean conversion occurs for the litrals "true" or "false" 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "=toBoolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


Hi @Nikolay Marinov . Kindly you can voteup as well, since only it increments the score for the badge(s), thanks in advance.
